# search bar for android 2.2 similar to uisearchbar in iPhone

Tags: android, android-widget, uisearchbar

I have an app in Android 2.2. In that I require a search widget which is similar to the UISearchBar of iPhone. How can I create that? Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Quick Search Box?

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html